# How to get a callback when you swipe left to dismiss a keyboard in android app?

Tags: android

In my app, I have the following functionality,

1. Click on edit text keyboard shows up
2. Enter some number
3. on IME_ACTION_DONE value is saved and keyboard is dismissed as expected
4. When I swipe left to go back (swipe left is back press on my device), I dont have any event to listen so that i can save the value or neglect the value and set it to old one.

How to listen for this swipe left to go back event?

Already tried the following:

1. OnKeyPress/OnKeyPreIme listener (only works for physical key press)
2. OnBackPressDispatcher (called only when swipe left takes you back from an activity, not called when the same action dismiss the keyboard)